# Unable to deploy ejb-based WSDL web-service in Glassfish 3

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy a weeb-service, generated from an EJB into glassfish, but, for some reason, my web service is never visible in Glassfish. The web-service is defined from an EJB interface as follows :

```
@Remote
@WebService
public interface TemplateEJBRemote {
    public abstract @WebResult(name="found") Template find(@WebParam(name="templateId", mode=Mode.IN) Long id);
}
```

This EJB interface has a Local implementation :

```
@Local
@Stateless
public class TemplateEJBImpl implements TemplateEJBRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName=NamingConstants.PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Template find(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Template.class, id);
    }
}
```

And they're both defined in a `war` module, which an `ear` module sends to Glassfish.

Those module produce correctly looking artefacts, including an `ear` with the correct `application.xml` :

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
version="6">
  <description>This is the project that will deliver a full usable
  EAR including all delivered components. All the project
  dependencies here will be included in this</description>
  <display-name>my-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>my-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/my-war</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

When deployed in Glassfish, all infos I can get is

```
E:\java-ext\glassfish3>bin\asadmin list-components --subcomponents
my-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  <ear, ejb, webservices, web>
  my-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war  <WebModule>
Command list-components executed successfully.
```

it seems to me that, were my web-service really deployed, it would appear below my `war` submodule, no ?

If not, what can I do to ensure my web-service is correctly defined and deployed ?

**[UPDATE 1]** In order to give some more informations, i created a smaller web-service endpoint, the *in*famous Hello world, coded as such :

```
@WebService
public class Hello {
    public String hello(String world) {
        return "Salut, "+world+" !";
    }
}
```

using this definition, it is a perfect Glassfiosh web-service :

[image]

But, as soon as I make it a bean, as such :

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class Hello {
    public String hello(String world) {
        return "Salut, "+world+" !";
    }
}
```

Things become a little different :

[image]

However, as log files told me, HelloService is still present :

```
[#|2011-03-31T17:55:55.059+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices|_ThreadID=339;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
```

autocat-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  listening at address at http://perigee-567125f:8080/HelloService/Hello|#]

I tried to apply the same logic to my initial bean, but with an infortunate result (a 404 error, of course). So I guess there is another issue hidden beneath. But which on ? I can't have any idea.

**[UPDATE 2]** To make things clear, the EJb I try to deploy is not visible as a web-service in Glassfish console, and its URL can't be pinged by any web client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at my copy of "EJB 3 In Action" and it says:

"A careful look at the code reveals that the @WebService endpoint interface looks similar to the remote interface. You might be tempted to mark the same interface as both a web service and a remote interface, like this:

```
@WebService
@Remote
public interface PlaceBid {
  public Long addBid(String bidderID, Long itemID, Double dibPrice);
}
```

**Unfortunately, although some vendors allow this as an extension, this is not part of the specification, and code that uses this particular attribute combination won't be portable."**

You're going to have to remove the @Remote

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some more troubleshooting.  Have a look at the logs in `glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs`.  Or if you have standalone or cluster nodes look in `glassfish3/glassfish/nodes/<nodename>/<instancename>/logs`.

Also, log into the admin page "http://localhost:4848", default username is admin, default password is adminadmin.  On the left there is a tree, find Applications, then your Ear should be listed there.  Click it and you'll see a list of modules and components.  If your web service is listed there you can click View Endpoint.  There is a built-in tester, and you can get the wsdl URL there too.

**update 1**:
You don't have any @WebMethod(operationName = "blah) on your hello().  Maybe if there are no WebMethods GlassFish decides it's not worth making your web service available.

**update 2**: More complete example of how my web service is put together inside the ear.  I'm pretty sure you don't have to separate the @WebService and @Stateless classes, but I like it that way because it feels cleaner and seems to separate the concerns.

**war:**

SomePojo.java:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="blah.com")
public class SomePojo {
    @EJB
    private BlahSessionLocal blahSession;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "user_id") Integer userId) throws Exception {
        return blahSession.hello(userId);
    }
}
```

**ejb jar:**

BlahSessionLocal.java

```
@Local
public interface BlahSessionLocal {
    String hello(Integer userId);
}
```

BlahSessionBean.java

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "BlahSession")
public class BlahSessionBean implements BlahSessionLocal {
    public String hello(Integer userId) {
        return "hello user " + userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I haven't got my web service packaged the same way as yours.  Mine is a pojo with only the @WebService(targetNamespace="blah.com").  Inside that pojo I have a @EJB private BlahSessionLocal blahSession.  Then @WebMethod(operationName = "someMethod") public SomeObject someMethod(@WebParam(name="param1") Integer param1) throws BlahException { return blahSession.someMethod(param1); }